# Failed to load resource (CSS,JS and picture files) after updating ASP.NET 5 from Beta6 to Beta7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

There is a working project on ASP.NET 5 Beta6 (MVC) and I want to update it to Beta7 version. So after this steps:

- Update the Visual Studio Tooling
- Update the DNX Runtime ([resource](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html))
- Update References in Projects (in `project.json` and `global.json` files)
- Check the [ASP.NET Announcements Page](https://github.com/aspnet/announcements/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A1.0.0-beta7) for changes (i had only change with namespace)
- Change wrong namespace

i'v got such message in google chrome console to all my content files after run:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: how did u do : Update the DNX Runtime ?

Comment: I used this [resource](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html) from "Install the .NET Version Manager (DNVM)" paragraph

Comment: how did you run? i mean have u used DNX command?

Comment: have u changed project.json?

Comment: only commands from resource that i wrote before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to update Startup.cs code according to [this announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/54).

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
                   {
                       routes.MapRoute(
                           name: "DefaultController",
                           template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                           );
                   });

        app.RunIISPipeline(); //New
    }
```

Comment: Trying this but IApplicationBuilder doesnt have that method nor any extension method.  Any idea which package I need to update to get this going?  Looks like Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions?

Comment: i have this packages in my proj:     "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta7",    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-beta7",    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta7". Are you shure that you use correct dnx ?